# connecting to redis service on dokku

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, dokku

I am having trouble getting my app to connect to my redis service on dokku.

My app is called api. I created a service for redis called redis. when I link the two together using `dokku reddis:link redis api`, I get a `REDIS_URL env` variable which is set to `redis://:fa7bb350b0d05809a670ea55be27a91816ebc4aa6f27613f2356c423f480f097@dokku-redis-redis:6379`. My redis instance in my app is set by doing the following:

```
const redis = new Redis({
    path: process.env.REDIS_URL
  });
```

when I look at the logs on dokku I get the following error message

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ENOENT redis://:fa7bb350b0d05809a670ea55be27a91816ebc4aa6f27613f2356c423f480f097@dokku-redis-redis:6379
```

I have also tried using port and host but I still get the same error message as above with the slight difference of the port not being there:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ENOENT redis://:fa7bb350b0d05809a670ea55be27a91816ebc4aa6f27613f2356c423f480f097@dokku-redis-redis
```

code looks like this

```
const redis = new Redis({
    port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT  ? process.env.REDIS_PORT  : '6379'),
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST
  });
```

I set the config variables in dokku to get REDIS_HOST and REDIS_PORT. I have a node.js app and I'm using the ioreddis package.

I'm out of ideas and haven't come across any other posts about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated